# How to change the background color of the toggle button on Android

Tags: android, togglebutton

I tried to change the background color of the toggle button using XML file as white color, but the toggle button is totally damaged. It looks like all the button was covered with white.

There is no indication of ON or OFF on the toggle button when I have changed the color of the toggle button to white. Is there is another way to change the background which will not damage the indication of the toggle button?

```
<ToggleButton android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
              android:layout_width="100px"
              android:layout_height="46px"
              android:background="#ffffff"
              android:layout_above ="@+id/save"
              android:textOn="DAY"
              android:textOff="NIGHT" />
```

This is how my XML code look for the toggle button.

Comment: Show us what you tried. Generally you need to use a [color state list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) or a [state list drawable](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) to do what you're describing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to change the background as you wish, but you have to use a selector like this as background:

```
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/some_image" />
<item
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/some_other_image" />
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/some_image1" />
<item
    android:state_focused="false"
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/other_image" />
</selector>
```

For @Drawable, etc. (you can use a color or make a gradient. Check [this](http://android-codes-examples.blogspot.com/2011/04/animated-customized-popup-transparent.html) for more information about gradients.

Answer (score 11):

Follow this way to make your `ToogleButton` have background color red when On and green when OFF

**First**, create `tooglebutton_selector.xml` in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/togglebutton_on"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/togglebutton_off"
        android:state_checked="false"
        />
</selector>
```

**Second**, create `togglebutton_on.xml` in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#ff0000" /> // red color
</shape>
```

**Third**, create `togglebutton_off.xml` in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid
        android:color="#00FF00" /> // green color
</shape>
```

**Finally**, in your ToggleButton

```
 <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/tooglebutton_selector" //set background of ToggleButton to tooglebutton_selector
            />
```

Comment: Can you help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39772456/change-togglebutton-color

Comment: Helpful answer, but from my own experince, it isn't necessary to create togglebutton_on.xml/togglebutton_off.xml if you just want to change color, you can pass the color resource as a parameter for the selector item directly

Answer (score -15):

When you decompile your SystemUI.apk, you should go to the following file: SystemUI/res/values/colors.xml

Then change the following line:

> **#ff000000**
>       #ffffffff
>       #80000000
>       #ffadc1d6
>       #ffffffff
>       #ffe6e6e6

Comment: There must be an easier way to do this?

Comment: the most unusual solution I've ever seen)))