# Change toggleButton color

Tags: android, listview, colors, togglebutton

> How to change the color of toggleButton in listView?

This is how I deigned my `toggleButton`

```
<ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/donePic"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="270dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:background="@drawable/selector"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn=""/>
```

**selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use tic -->
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/done"
        android:state_checked="true" >
        <solid
            android:color="@color/red" />
    </item>
    <!-- When not selected, use un tic-->
    <item android:drawable="@mipmap/done"
        android:state_checked="false">
        <solid
            android:color="@color/green" />
    </item>

</selector>
```

**MyActivity**

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { // inside adapter class
        ViewHolder holder;   
        ToggleButton toggle;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_to_do, null);
            toggle =(ToggleButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.donePic);
            toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    if (isChecked) {
                        Log.e("A","a");
                    } else {
                        // The toggle is disabled
                    }
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        return convertView;
    }
```

It displays `log` when `toggleButton` is clicked, but the color still remain white(its original color). How can I change the color of `toggleButton`  ?

**Updated**

I have **updated** my code, but the color still remains white ! I want to use the **done.png** and I have placed it to `res/drawable/done.png`.

**selector**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- When selected, use tic -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on"
        android:state_checked="true" >
    </item>
    <!-- When not selected, use un tic-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off"
        android:state_checked="false">
    </item>

</selector>
```

**toggle_on**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/done"
        android:state_checked="true">
        <solid
            android:color="@color/green" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

**toggle_off**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/done"
        android:state_checked="false">
        <solid
            android:color="@color/red" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: **1** - This `<item android:drawable="@mipmap/done"` is the same for both selected and unselected states: it should be 2 different drawables.  **2** - The `mipmaps` folder is to be used for the **app icon only**.

Comment: @Rotwang  `android:tint` cannot be used in **selector** ?

Comment: the `android:tint` attribute does not work on all API Levels.

Comment: @Rotwang thanks for telling

Comment: Then what are the way to achieve this :(

Comment: Put the drawables in your drawable-*dpi folders, as usual. Use 2 different drawables for the 2 different states.

Comment: @Rotwang Siir I follow vrund's answer but where should I put this `<item android:drawable="@mipmap/done"/>` as I want to use this icon

Comment: ... in the `res/drawable-*dpi` folder? Where * depends on the device density (l,m, h, xh,xxh, xxxh).

Comment: No, the `done` is an icon where I place it in `res/mipmap-hdpi` folder.  I want to use it for 2 different states. I just want to change their color.

Comment: NO. `mipmap-*dpi` is **only and exclusively** to be used for your **app** icon. Not for all the other icons in your app. Make 2 drawables: `done_on` and `done_off` and refer those ones in your selector.

Comment: ok, I have moved the `done` to `drawable-*dpi`.Refer to vrund's answer, I also make two drawable folder....But where should I put `<item android:drawable="@drawable/done`  so I can use the image?

Comment: Put your selector in `res/drawable`. It's a drawable, and doesn't depend on the density.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124559/discussion-between-john-and-rotwang).

Comment: @Rotwang Sir please check my post again..Thanks

Comment: `I want to use the done.png` as I said, you should use **2 pngs**. I'd name them `done_on.png` and `done_off.png`

Comment: OK,but how about the color?

Comment: Make them differ by some detail. I.e.: the color. Otherwise, if they are identical, you won't see any change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this way.

**ToggleButton :**

```
<ToggleButton 
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:textOn="On"
    android:textOff="Off"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_day_bg_selector" />
```

**toggle_day_bg_selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_off"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_on"
        android:state_checked="true"/>
</selector>
```

**toggle_on.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval"
    >
    <solid android:color="@color/red" />

</shape>
```

**toggle_off.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/green" />

</shape>
```

Hope this will help.

**EDIT :**

use this drawable files for showing images on `ToggleButton`

**toggle_off.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_green_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

**toggle_on.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <shape
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_red_dark" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

happy coding..

Comment: Will this give me a tick togglebutton ?

Comment: you can modify shape file as per you requirement. you can wrap `<shape>` inside `<item android:drawable="@drawable/done">` inside `layer-list`. i am not sure about that. i have't tested it yet.

Comment: thanks for your answer. If I don't want to have shape, just the tick with different color, is it possible ?

Comment: ofc. but it will just overrode default shape of you togglebutton.